# subprocess.Popen and passing arguments (quoting?)

Tags: python, subprocess

I have been trying to run a process with `Popen` without any success. The parts of the code are:

```
setCmd=['--set-tag="COMPOSER=J S Bach"', '--set-tag="ALBUM=Goldbergovske variace BWV 988"', '--set-tag="TRACKNUMBER=01"', '--set-tag="TITLE=Aria"']
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["metaflac"] + setCmd + [file],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It seems metaflac does not run. A simple test

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["metaflac"] + ["--version"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

works well suggesting the problem might be in `setCmd`. More specifically I would guess the quoting as is almost always the source of trouble.

How can i correct the code?

I also tried multiple variations like:

```
args=" ".join(setCmd)
```

and then prependning and appending `args` so that I can run it like:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

where

```
args='metaflac --set-tag="COMPOSER=J S Bach" --set-tag="ALBUM=Goldbergovske variace BWV 988" --set-tag="TRACKNUMBER=01" --set-tag="TITLE=Aria" filename.flac'
```

does not work either.

Comment: What are `args` and `file`? `setCmd` is never used.

Comment: It was a typo, I am sorry, the question is corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to use `setCmd` instead of `args` in the `Popen` line?

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["metaflac"] + setCmd + [file],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Also, you may need to remove the double quotes in the elements of `setCmd`; i.e.,

```
setCmd=['--set-tag=COMPOSER=J S Bach',
        '--set-tag=ALBUM=Goldbergovske variace BWV 988',
        '--set-tag=TRACKNUMBER=01',
        '--set-tag=TITLE=Aria']
```

They're important when typing the command into a terminal because they let the shell know how to split the arguments, but, here, you've already split the arguments into a list of strings. `metaflac` may be able to deal with them, but maybe not.

Comment: Is there any way to send an execution command as is with quotes as I suggested in the edited question at the end? I am quite sure I was able to do it once, maybe not with `Popen` but there was a trick, I just cannot remember.

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to use `shell=True` to tell it to treat the `args` argument as a single shell command, like `args='metaflac --set-tag="COMPOSER=J S Bach" etc...'` and `subprocess.Popen(args=args, shell=True)`